# Air Resistance Speed Proportionality

Tags: mathematical-modeling, classical-mechanics

I am considering a ball that is being thrown and travelling in the air. I know that the air resistance acting on it is proportional to the difference between the velocity of the ball and the air, so say air resistance = $-k(\dot{r}- u)$.

Question - what is the value of $k$, i.e that is suitable for a ball thrown over a distance of say, around $15$ metres. I know there isn’t a universal value, but what approximate value could I use for a model. Would it have to be between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: It is more realistic to use a quadratic velocity dependence, if you double the relative velocity, then every second the ball will be affected by twice the mass of air, each packet of which will transfer twice the impulse, so there will be four times the force.

Comment: @WW1 Okay I understand that, but this is the method I have chosen so I’ll stick with that for now. Can you tell me what I should do to assign a value for $k$ please ?

Comment: Use [terminal velocity examples](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/airfri2.html#c3). When an object reaches terminal velocity $mg=kv$. So for a baseball $k\approx 0.05$

Comment: @Andrei Thanks! What is $v$ though in my scenario that I posted ? Like how would I work it out ?

Comment: @Andrei Because I’m confused how how you got $0.05$ for the baseball. I know you roughly know the mass but what about $v$

Comment: @Andrei Sorry ignore that. You got the values from the link you attached!

Comment: @Andrei Do you know what the terminal velocity of a rugby ball is ? I can’t seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: @NikitaMazepin Sorry, I have no idea. But you can probably search for an American football (look relatively similar). For example, https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82228213.pdf

Comment: @Andrei Thanks! I looked at your link and the terminal velocity wasn’t listed there. Could I use the terminal velocity of a soccer ball instead and say that this is an underestimate then because I can’t find the terminal velocity of an object similar to a right ball.

Comment: @Andrei I got a value of $0.157$ for $k$. Does this sound realistic to you for an American football / rugby ball ?

Comment: Yes. It is slightly larger than a baseball, but same order of magnitude

Comment: @Andrei If $k$ is higher and closer to $1$, does that mean there is more air resistance ?

Comment: @NikitaMazepin correct. Note that it can be greater than 1 as well